# How do I report bugs in Stack Exchange (e.g., a voting bug in Area 51)?

Tags: discussion, voting, area-51

How would I report bugs in Stack Exchange (e.g., a voting bug on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq))?

See printscreen after voting:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You'd point out bugs that affect one site only on that site's meta. For Area 51, that's [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug)

If you find a bug that affects all sites, you can still use the site meta where you found the bug, but they would also be valid on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Just pick one as cross-posting is not allowed.

Note that Area 51 doesn't get much love; the non-meta codebase is very old.